# Python SCons Action?

Tags: scons

I've been searching the documentation for a long time and still can't figure this out.

In the SCons documentation, there is discussion about adding a PreAction or PostAction. In the examples, they call an example method:

```
foo = Program('foo.c')
AddPreAction(foo, 'pre_action')
```

This calls 'pre_action' before 'foo.c' is compiled and linked. However, there is no explanation about what format 'pre_action' must take.

I have discovered that there are several pre-built actions, such as 'Copy'. However, I cannot find the source of 'Copy' to reverse-engineer it and write my own.

Can anyone point me to a guide as to how to create my own Actions? I either need an interface for calling  my own method such as 'pre_action' above, or a guide for writing an Action class.

Really, even just some example code that is actually complete enough to use would be helpful...

Comment: Is this really about "python scons action"  or just an action to add to a AddPreAction() ?

Comment: Not the best question name, I admit. My original name was far more informative - something like 'How can I create my own Action in SCons?'. However, the UI would not allow me to use it. It claimed that the question didn't match its standards. I tried to improve the question a bunch of different ways. In the end, the only one I could get past the UI was this one. It's a bit of an own-goal on their part, I think.

Comment: Wow that's frustrating, and not helpful on SO's part.

Comment: @AviChapman: It seems that title filter doesn't like the word "my" in the title. You could title your question e.g. with "How can I create custom Action in SCons?"

Answer (score 1):

The manpage section [Action Objects](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#action_objects) lists the types of things that can be passed to the `Action` factory function to create an action; that is also what you pass to `AddPostAction` and `AddPreAction` as the second argument - that is, either an Action already made by a previous call to `Action`, or something that can be converted into one like a command string, or a list of such, or a function with appropriate signature. Pre/Post will simply call the `Action` function with that argument.  So in that section, where there's an example with a call to `Action`, you could just plug that argument into `AddPreAction`, or you could save the result of calling `Action` and give that as the argument to `AddPreAction`.

The amount of flexibility here makes it a little tricky to document concisely.

(btw the source to `Copy` is a function called `copy_func` but you probably don't want to use that form because it's a couple of extra levels of abstraction you won't need)